# Sub selects within MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I am wanting to alias 3 variables in my query, `total_time_taken` and `average` and `request_count`.

The average is meant to calculate the `total_time_taken / request_count` to return `average` however it is giving me a syntax error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select(created_at, assigned_at, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, requests.created_at, r' at line 4
```

The query is below.

```
select
    *,
    COUNT(*) as request_count,
    select(created_at, assigned_at, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, requests.created_at, requests.assigned_at)) from requests) as total_time_taken,
    total_time_taken / request_count as average
from
    `requests`
where
    `deleted_at` is null
and
    `submitted_at` >= '2017-03-30 00:00:00'
and
    `requests`.`deleted_at` is null
group by
    `engineer_id`
limit 5
```

Comment: You are missing an `(` in front of the 2nd `select`

Comment: the sub select needs to be wrapped in ()? @Shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of the subqueries, why not just take the sum as you aggregate by each engineer?  Alse, you were doing `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`, which usually doesn't work, and usually is wrong, because it would include non aggregate columns.  Instead, just select `engineer_id` or an aggregate of some other column.

```
SELECT
    engineer_id,
    COUNT(*) AS request_count,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, assigned_at)) AS total_time_taken,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, assigned_at)) /
    COUNT(*) AS average
FROM requests
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND
      submitted_at >= '2017-03-30 00:00:00' AND
      deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY engineer_id
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Getting the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, requests.created_at, requests.assigned_at)) / ' at line 5`

However you have nailed exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You probably want to use `ORDER BY` with this query, since you are using `LIMIT`.  As it stands now, you would be returning 5 arbitrary engineers, probably not what you want.

Comment: As I mentioned above, add `ORDER BY <something>` to the end of the query to get five engineers according to some order, assuming you want that.